# How to check if JSON object is null in Java

Tags: java, json

I am working on an app that performs a search on my server, data transmission is based on JSON, but I am experiencing problems when parsing the results, if there is no network I get a NullException when getting information from the JSON object, I tried checking for connection, if connected to the internet then it can proceed but in situations where it had internet when requesting for data and lost it when receiving it from the server I get a NullException too, What I thought was checking if the JSON object is null before tempering with it, but all methods of checking for null I know have failed, below is my JAVA code:

```
 mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


            try {

                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query", searchbox.getText().toString()));


                Log.d("request!", "starting Search");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(SEARCH_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                // check your log for json response
               if(json.toString().isEmpty())
                {
                   Log.d("Search Attempt", json.toString());
               }

               else{
                   search = new SEARCH();
                    search.cancel(true);



                }

                Log.d("Search Attempt", json.toString());
```

Comment: Where does the NPE occur? I'd think at `if(json.toString().isEmpty())`, correct?

Comment: IsNotNull(Object); this is how to test for null

Comment: @Felk yes right there

Comment: @RiteshK so in my case it is IsNotNull(json)?

Comment: @Chrome yup you are right

Comment: @Chrome its assertNotNull

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Please download necessary JUnit JAR file to enable assertion**

```
mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


            try {

                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query", searchbox.getText().toString()));


                Log.d("request!", "starting Search");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(SEARCH_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                 AssertNotNull(json); //for asserting 

                 // To prevent the code form breaking 
                // check your log for json response
               if(json.toString().isEmpty())
                {
                   Log.d("Search Attempt", json.toString());
               }

               else{
                   search = new SEARCH();
                    search.cancel(true);



                }

                Log.d("Search Attempt", json.toString());
```

Comment: @Chrome you have to import org.junit for making assertion

Comment: @Chrome Link to how to get started http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_environment_setup.htm

Comment: Thank you very much, you really have been of great help.